# graphicsmagick crop depending on original image size (resuse readstream)

Tags: node.js, image-processing, meteor, graphicsmagick

I'm using Meteor's collection-fs packages to upload images, and I want to cut a thumbnail out of the centre of each image using `gm(readStrem).crop()`. Problem is, the `x` and `y` offsets for `crop` depend on the size of the original image, image sizes will vary, and I can't use the same reasdStream twice.

This breaks:

```
var xOff = 0;
var yOff = 0;
var thumbnailWidth = 450;
var thumbnailHeight = 600;
gm(readStream).size(function (err, dimensions) {
   if ( dimensions ) {
     xOff = (dimensions.width - thumbnailWidth) / 2;
     yOff = (dimensions.height - thumbnailHeight) / 2;
   }
   gm(readStream)
     .crop(thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight, xOff, yOff)
     .stream()
     .pipe(writeStream);
})
```

The dimensions return but the second use of readStream returns `Error: gm().stream() or gm().write() with a non-readable stream`

I've seen a few other answers related to this but none help me because the package forces me to `pipe(writeStream)`; I can't just do '.writeAsync()' I tried all sorts of other tricks that didn't work, including:

- cloning the stream to get the size and then using the original for the synchronous transform and save (in a timer)
- calling the whole thing synchronously (silly idea, but worth a shot)

If anybody has any ideas, I'd really appreciate your input.

Thanks!
db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to determine the file size on the client, append those details to the fileObj before writing, and then call crop normally on the server during write.

```
var cropInfo = fileObj.cropInfo
gm(readStream)
     .crop(cropInfo.width, cropInfo.height, cropInfo.x, cropInfo.y)
     .stream()
     .pipe(writeStream);
```

Not quite ideal, but it works.

Comment: We need to check it in server-side, because this may harmful for system

Answer (score 2):

This works and doesn't rely on the client, which makes it safer:

```
var xOff = 0;
var yOff = 0;
var thumbnailWidth = 450;
var thumbnailHeight = 600;
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).size(
  {bufferStream: true},
  function (err, dimensions) {
    if (dimensions) {
      xOff = (dimensions.width - thumbnailWidth) / 2;
      yOff = (dimensions.height - thumbnailHeight) / 2;
    }
    this.crop(thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight, xOff, yOff);
    this.stream((err, stdout, stderr) => {
      stdout.pipe(writeStream);
    });
  }
);
```